# Elegant way to tell `pandoc` to produce `.tex` without a preamble so they can be _included_ with latex?

Tags: include, latex, markdown, pandoc, tex

I am writing a text in `markdown` to pipe into `pandoc` to produce `html` and `tex` files.
This works great for single files and linked html files.
Now I want to build a single pdf of the multiple tex files using a main file which calls the tex files with `\include{foo}`.
Which fails with each `.tex` file having a full preamble.

How would I tell pandoc to produce a *includable* tex-file?
Or am I on the wrong track? If so, how can I stich together a pdf from several markdown files?

PS I am here [because of this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295180/where-to-ask-pandoc-questions)

Comment: There are several latex class and packages which allow you to include documents with full preambles. Have a look at e.g. docmute or some of these https://www.ctan.org/recommendations/combine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized I still had the `-s` option in my `pandoc` command.
With out it, pandoc produce just the text body and everything works.
Bonus: In fact, want to use `\input{foo}` to be able to carry label over several latex files.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need "includable" documents, there are several latex class and packages which allow you to include documents with full preambles, e.g. `docmute`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{docmute}

\begin{document}

test

\include{document} % document with full preamble

\end{document}
```

(or have a look at some of these https://www.ctan.org/recommendations/combine )

---

Or if you already have the pdf files of the individual documents, you can stitch them together using the `pdfpages` package.